# Is there a way to change ownership of a question?

Tags: support

The user who asked [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5172/the-table-i-built-wobbles-shakes-side-to-side) seems to be having a lot of trouble with the website.

He originally posted the question as user "user3080" and added replies to comments in answers as user "user3081" and "rumple".  One of the two was deleted.  He is now [editing the leftover answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1941) to try to respond to my new comment.

I'm guessing he's having a hard time figuring out how to respond to comments since his "rumple" account now lacks the reputation available under "user3080". Hence the question about changing question ownership.

<sub>Note: I'm using masculine pronouns for simplicity;  I have no clue which gender the user is.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Users can log onto the site from different means using different email accounts. It is possible for them to merge them, though they aren't required to do so.

They just need to go [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and follow the instructions.

Also see [this post on Meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/244706)